Join two strings to use in a html attribute
I'm getting:
<tr data-providernum="12345" data-providername="JARVIS," claire="" elizabeth="">

when I want:
<tr data-providernum="12345" data-providername="JARVIS, claire" >

My code is :
var lastname      = record[1];
var firstname     = record[2];

var fullnames = lastname+ ', ' + firstname;

var newRow = "<tr data-providernum=" + providerNum + " data-providername=" + fullnames + "><td>" + providerNum + "</td><td>" + lastname + "</td><td>" + firstname + "</td></tr>";
$("#searchresult").append(newRow);  

I've tried different combinations of double and single quotes to build my  string,  but now I'm just spinning my wheels.
How do I achieve this?

wrap with single quotation ''...

Create HTML elements as opposed to strings using jQuery's creation method. This will avoid you having to nest or escape quote characters or worry about any other HTML entities in your variables.


const providerNum = '12345';
const record = [, 'JARVIS', 'claire'];

const lastname = record[1];
const firstname = record[2];
const fullnames = `${lastname}, ${firstname}`;

// Create elements, not strings
const newRow = $('<tr>', {
  'data-providernum': providerNum,
  'data-providername': fullnames,
}).append(
  $('<td>', { text: providerNum }),
  $('<td>', { text: lastname }),
  $('<td>', { text: firstname }),
);

$('#searchresult').append(newRow);
console.log('row data attributes:', newRow.data());
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<table id="searchresult" border="1"></table>




While you're here, it might be worth reading Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names
